# Enumerating in reverse with correct indices

Tags: arrays, swift, enumeration

One nice syntax in Swift is the ability to enumerate both the index and entry of an array as a loop like so:

```
for (index, entry) in enumerate(myArray) {
    doSomething(index, entry)
}
```

And it's also possible to easily start from the end of the array using the `reverse` condition like this:

```
for (index, entry) in enumerate(reverse(myArray)) {
    doSomething(index, entry)
}
```

However, the problem with this is that `index` now counts from the end of the array (i.e- the last element is index zero), meaning that it has to be corrected if I need an index value for the actual location of `entry` in `myArray`, which loses some of the elegance of this.

The alternative is to do something like this:

```
for (var index, entry) in enumerate(reverse(myArray)) {
    index = (myArray.count - 1) - index
    doSomething(index, entry)
}
```

It's not the end of the world, but I'm wondering whether there's an alternative that I've overlooked that could allow me to enumerate in reverse, but with the correct index values being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a solution:

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for index in reverse(0..<myArray.count) {
    println("\(index): \(myArray[index])")
}
```

**Edit:**

If you really do not want to access your entry via index inside the `for` body, you might try:

```
for (index, entry) in zip(reverse(0..<myArray.count), reverse(myArray)) {
    println("\(index): \(entry)")
}
```

or

```
for (index, entry) in reverse(0..<myArray.count)
    .map({ ($0, myArray[$0])}) {

    println("\(index): \(entry)")

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It seems the first option (reversing the range) is the one I'll go for; while functionally it's the same as utogaria's answer I think it's a little neater for stepping through consecutive elements.

Of course it seems I can't pull entries out as index/entry pairs like I'd hoped to, but perhaps in future Apple will add the concept of two-way enumerators, or reversible enumerators. Perhaps I could add it via extension? Probably overkill, but it's nice that it may be an option!

Answer (score 3):

When you apply reverse() to an array, the result is already a new array, naturally the index should reflect the new array. I found another way to enumerate reversely, I suppose this is elegant enough:

```
let names = ["Jack", "Lucy", "Kate"]

for index in stride(from: count(names) - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
    println("\(index): \(names[index])")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think to complicated:

```
for var i = array.count - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
    let item = array[i]
}
```